# Conflicting components in scope

Tags: javascript, scope, vue.js

I am trying to abstract a Google Places Autocomplete input component in order to use it multiple times.

However, data and methods overlap when I instantiate more than 1 of the following component. (the same `place` gets logged)

```
<template>
  <input :ref="inputRef" type="text">
</template>

<script>
var autocompleteInput

export default {
  props: ['inputRef'],
  methods: {
    fetchAddress() {
      var place = autocompleteInput.getPlace();
      console.log(place)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    autocompleteInput = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(this.$refs[this.inputRef]),
    {types: ['address']});
    autocompleteInput.addListener('place_changed', this.fetchAddress);
    console.log(this.$refs[this.inputRef])
  }
}
</script>
```

My guess is that `var autocompleteInput` is the issue, because it seems to be out of scope.

However I can't figure out how to scope it down.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The component will only be created / defined once, therefore there is only one `autocompleteInput`.

Make it a `data` property to isolate it to each rendered instance

```
data () {
  return {
    autocompleteInput: null
  }
}
```

and reference it via `this.autocompleteInput` in your methods / lifecycle-hooks.

Comment: That did it. Thanks. The power of basics.